# Installing puppet on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, puppet, agent

At the moment I have a little issue with installing/downloading puppet on CentOS 7.
The command that have been used is:
'sudo rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlab...l-7.noarch.rpm'

Then I'm getting the following error:
'Retreiving https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlab...l-7.noarch.rpm
curl: (6) could not resolve host: yum.puppetlabs.com; unkown error
error: skipping https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlab...l-7.noarch.rpm transfer failed'

The link (above) is working whenever I try to download it outside of Linux / VirtualBox, but not inside.
Also ping some random website doesn't work but I have read that's a commmon issue at VirtualBox.
It even can't ping my own router, and it's giving me this error:
'connect: Network is unreachable'

At the moment I have put the network options to NAT.
I'm running CentOS inside VirtualBox.
Anyone know the issue of this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the network options to Bridged Adaptor and restart. if you have DHCP setup this should work without any problem else set IP manually.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging your post with VirtualBox might help.

But anyway, the most common cause of this is VirtualBox DNS problems, I usually just change the `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `8.8.8.8` and that fixes it. You can also just reload the VM.

Comment: Added the nameserver 8.8.8.8 to the resolv.conf, but still getting the same error.

Comment: What's the output for `nslookup yum.puppetlabs.com` ?

can you even ping your home router or 8.8.8.8?

Comment: No, I couldn't. But I solved the problem by simply reïnstalling. Installed some packages and turning the internet connection switch on before the installation (doh).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is by simply reïnstalling. Installed some packages and turning the internet connection switch on before the installation (doh)